Can a JSON Schema property name start with an integer?
Are there any rules for writing JSON Schema field name?
I have a JSON schema with a field name quoted in double quotes and it starts it integer.
But the same schema is not accepted by the big data tools!
If yes then why??
{ "properties": {"5checkSum": true }}


What do you mean with "is not accepted by the big data tools!"?

JSON Schema itself has no restrictions on property names.  Other tooling may have restrictions, though.  They should document such restrictions if they do.

RFC8259 which JSON Schema uses as a normative reference, does not constrain member(property) names beginning with a number
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html
